# Why is self-referencing pointer or this out of scope in button?

Tags: java, swing, this, self-reference, state-pattern

I'm trying to produce a dynamic canvas using the Swing library with the State pattern. My code can compile but with red marks all over the console when my buttons are pressed.

The problem: my self-referencing pointer or reserved word *this* is out of scope in button. I want to be able to access the class without any static.

**Error: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method handlePush(SP) in the type State is not applicable for the arguments (new ActionListener(){})**

This is is the canvas class.

```
public class SP extends JPanel{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private State state = null; 

public static void main(String[] args){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            createAndShowCanvasGUI();
        }
    });
}
public SP(State state ){
    this.state = state;
    init();
}
public SP(){
    this(new BlackState());
}
public static void createAndShowCanvasGUI(){
    JFrame frm = new JFrame("State Pattern");
    frm.setVisible(true);
    frm.setSize(400, 400);
    frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frm.setContentPane(new SP());
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.setColor(state.getColor());
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    repaint();
}
public void init(){
    JButton push = new JButton("Push");
    JButton pull = new JButton("Pull");

    push.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
            if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("Push")){
                state.handlePush(this);
            }
        }
    });
    pull.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
            if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("Pull")){
                state.handlePull(this);
            }
        }
    });

    add(push);
    add(pull);
}
public State setState(State newState){
    State oldState = state; 
    state = newState;
    return oldState;
}
public State getState(){
    return state; 
    }
}
```

This is the logical state design

```
public abstract class State {

public abstract void handlePull(SP p);
public abstract void handlePush(SP p);
public abstract Color getColor(); 
}
```

Here is one variation of the State

```
public class GreenState extends State{
@Override
public void handlePull(SP c) {
    c.setState(new BlackState());
}
@Override
public void handlePush(SP c) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    c.setState(new RedState());
}
@Override
public Color getColor() {
    return Color.GREEN;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your use of `this` does not refer to an `SP` object, but rather an `ActionListener` object.

```
push.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("Push")){
            state.handlePush(this);  // *this* refers to anonymous inner-class ActionListener 
        }
    }
});
```

instead, you need to qualify your `this` reference

```
push.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("Push")){
            state.handlePush(SP.this);  // *this* now refers to SP
        }
    }
});
```

The change here is `SP.this` instead of `this`.

Alternatively, you can also assign `this` to a final variable outside of the anonymous class, then reference that variable from inside

```
final SP thisSp = this;
push.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("Push")){
            state.handlePush(thisSp);  // same as using SP.this
        }
    }
});
```